# What is CLI equivalent for "Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project" in Next.js 13.1.2

Tags: next.js

We have an automated image creation pipeline that uses CLI to create a default Next.js app and install dependencies, etc.

This is our code:

```
WORKDIR /

RUN npx --yes create-next-app next --use-npm --js --eslint

WORKDIR /next
```

Yesterday Next.js team released their `13.1.2` version, which broke this line.

They have added a new CLI option that asks:

> ? Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? › No / Yes

What is the option to automate the answer for this option?

Comment: can I ask you what are the advantages of using the src directory instead of pages?

Comment: @sekmo there is no advantanges for us. We just want to automate project creation process.

Answer (score 1):

The option you are looking for is **--src-dir**. So to automate the initialization using src directory you should run:

```
npx create-next-app --src-dir
```

Check documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/create-next-app)